# How do I get 1Password to work in Safari Technology Preview?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, 1password

If I launch STP » Navigate to a site's login form » Invoke 1Password to fill my credentials, Safari launches and my Login item doesn't fill in Safari Technology Preview. Why?

Comment: Tech Preview is beta, and beta is beta because it still has bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, in order to use 1Password (or any Safari App Extensions) with Safari Technology Preview, STP needs to be set as your default browser:

Click the Apple menu  in the top left corner of your screen » **System Preferences** » **General**. Then change your **Default Web Browser** to Safari Technology Preview.

You can follow this thread in the 1Password support forums if you're interested in learning more:
[[1Password Support Forum - Safari Technology Preview](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/comment/427968/#Comment_427968)]